# How to synchronize Template in Expression engine

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three sites working in EE using MSM and I am using subscription addon of http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/subscriptions/#installing-and-updating-subscriptions I have created two templates group `subs` and `subs_emails` as described on this link now this two are showing in Template synchronization but how to synchronize them as described on website http://www.devdemon.com/documentation/subscriptions/#installing-and-updating-subscriptions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the files over from `/system/expressionengine/third_party/subs/templates` over to whatever template you are using to house template as files. For example in my case I would be moving them to `/../templates/default_site` as I store my templates above webroot in a folder called templates. I have never used the Subscriptions module but make sure the folders in question have .group at the end `subs.group` & `subs_emails.group`. After you have done that you will go to Design > Templates > Template Synchronization and select the folders in question and click Submit.

Comment: Hello,  how to do that on EE 3? I'm just having this issue (in 3.x) after many years on 1.x and 2.x